# Get all users who placed requests in last three years

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I would like to get all the list of users who placed requests in the last three years.

Requests( request_id, request_day, user_id, userprofile_id )

Am I doing it right?

```
SELECT user_id
  FROM requests
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM request_day) IN ( 2014,2015,2016 )
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3;
```

Comment: I don't know, are you doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current approach is *almost* correct.  All you need to do is to count by the *distinct* number of years:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM requests
WHERE YEAR(request_day) IN (2014, 2015, 2016)
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(request_day)) = 3;
```

If the `DISTINCT` count of years is 3, then it implies that a user has all three of the years in your `WHERE IN` clause.

Note that another way to do this would be conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT user_id
FROM requests
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(request_day) = 2014 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(request_day) = 2015 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN YEAR(request_day) = 2016 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
```

This approach would scale better if your query were to get more complex.

Comment: Thanks for the solution... I liked the second one!! :)